# Dynamic shape and Indexing with Tensorflow

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow, neural-network, symbolic-math

I am adapting [this MLP tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html) for Tensorflow.

However, I can't figure out how to properly and efficiently compute the negative-log-likelihood. When I try to build the following graph, an error occur :

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784), name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,), name='y')

# [...] Define the tf.Variables W_hidden, W_out b_hidden, b_out

hidden_act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W_hidden) + b_hidden)
p_y_given_x = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden_act, W_out) + b_out)

ind_i = tf.range(tf.shape(p_y_given_x)[0])
ind_j = y
nLL = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(p_y_given_x[ind_i, ind_j]))
```

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_2' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?,10], [2,?], [2,?], [2]

**Is it possible to index a tensor with dynamic shape in the graph?**

**What am I missing?**

P.s. When I evaluate (sess.run(...)) individually the `p_y_given_x`, `ind_i` and `ind_j` tensors, I can then easily index the resulting ndarray `p_y_given_x` with the two index vectors. The problem is that I don't know how to do that symbolically in TF.

Comment: To slice/join tensors, you could try [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/array_ops).

Comment: Have you found a solution?